# Placing controls under User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls

I'm new to WPF, and I am creating a user control as follows:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication3.MyUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         x:Name="MyUserControl2"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Background="Coral">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Content="a" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Button Content="b" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Button Content="c" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="3"/>
</Grid>
```

This produces the following layout, when the orange area is the content preseter:

[image: the orange area is the content presenter]

In the main window that uses the user control, I want to inject controls into the content preseter

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <local:MyUserControl>
        <local:MyUserControl.Content>
            <Button Content="d"/>
        </local:MyUserControl.Content>
    </local:MyUserControl>
</Grid>
```

I would expect the get the following layout:

[image]

but instead the entire user control gets overlapped by button d.

How do I manage to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing `button` itself in `Main Window` -

```
<Grid>
    <local:MyUserControl/>
    <Button Content="d"/>
</Grid>
```

OR

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
       <DataTemplate x:Key="MyContent">
          <Button Content="d"/>
       </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <local:MyUserControl/>
</Grid>
```

and in your User Control -

```
 <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="3" ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource MyContent}"/>
```

Comment: Did you try using the `DataTemplate` approach?

Comment: your second solution works! thanks! The only not so elegant thing about it is that every one that uses this user control will have to know they have to specify a data template named 'MyContent' which is kinda ugly design-wise...

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that that won't work. When you set the content of MyControl to the button you're saying that the whole content of the user control should be the Button. I think you need to have a property on your user control then bind the contentpresenter to that.

So Something like MyUserControl.SubContent {get; set;} then you can bind the ContentPresenter to that.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't understand it correctly but I thought the whole purpose of the contentPresenter control is to consume the content of its parent control and display it without having to bind it